# Pass Compass values

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0, sensors

I would like to use my compass' values to make a 3D compass. When I'm writing out the values in a textView, it work properly. But when I'm trying to pass the values to an external variable, adn the write out these external variable's value in a TextView, they always show ZERO VALUES. So is there anyway to use the sensor's values in a GLSurfaceView?

This code works:

```
  @Override
     public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
          switch(event.sensor.getType()){
                case Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER:
                    for(int i =0; i < 3; i++){
                        valuesAccelerometer[i] = event.values[i];
                    }
                    break;
                case Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD:
                    for(int i =0; i < 3; i++){
                        valuesMagneticField[i] = event.values[i];
                    }
                    break;
            }

            boolean success = SensorManager.getRotationMatrix(matrixR, matrixI, valuesAccelerometer, valuesMagneticField);
            if(success){
                SensorManager.getOrientation(matrixR, matrixValues);
                double azimuth = Math.toDegrees(matrixValues[0]);
                double pitch = Math.toDegrees(matrixValues[1]);
                double roll = Math.toDegrees(matrixValues[2]);

                readingAzimuth.setText("Azimuth: " + String.valueOf(azimuth));
                readingPitch.setText("Pitch: " + String.valueOf(pitch));
                readingRoll.setText("Roll: " + String.valueOf(roll));
            }
        }
```

But this code doesn't:

```
 public double azimuth;
 public double pitch 
 public double roll

 @Override
 public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
          switch(event.sensor.getType()){
                case Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER:
                    for(int i =0; i < 3; i++){
                        valuesAccelerometer[i] = event.values[i];
                    }
                    break;
                case Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD:
                    for(int i =0; i < 3; i++){
                        valuesMagneticField[i] = event.values[i];
                    }
                    break;
            }

            boolean success = SensorManager.getRotationMatrix(matrixR, matrixI, valuesAccelerometer, valuesMagneticField);
            if(success){
                SensorManager.getOrientation(matrixR, matrixValues);
                azimuth = Math.toDegrees(matrixValues[0]);
                pitch = Math.toDegrees(matrixValues[1]);
                roll = Math.toDegrees(matrixValues[2]);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I would assume you might set these text values before they are assigned. You may find useful to looking to lifecycles.

I could help more with more data.

Comment: I would like to use the azimuth, pitch, and roll variables in a different method

Comment: my best guess would be your function is running before the assignments have done, so that's why they are zero because they are not yet assigned. You should call your method after you get the data from the sensor module.